# how to disable file association for my Android app?

Tags: android, android-video-player, file-association

I've got app, which uses third party video stream player (one activity and a lot of .so dependencies) to play the HLS streams.

My issue is that if anybody click on video file on SD-card (e.g. in total commander ), system shows list of potential video players and my app is in the list. How to prevent it? My app is not intended for this action to play video files. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to prevent it?

Somewhere in your manifest, you have an `<intent-filter>` on an `<activity>` that advertises that you know how to `VIEW` video files. Remove that `<intent-filter>`, and that should clear up this problem.